# What is the nominalization of the verb "Load"?

Tags: verbs

**For example:**

Extract > Extracting > Extraction

Transform > Transforming > Transformation

Load > Loading > **???**

Comment: What do you mean by "passive verb for load"? "extracting" and "transforming" are *-ing* forms (variously classified as gerunds, present participles, nouns or adjectives depending on their function) and "extraction" and "transformation" are nominalizations. None of these are related to the grammatical construction called the "passive voice"

Comment: I think you need to read a bit more about passive verbs. There's no passive verb in your example (it's actually possible to read the whole question as not containing a single verb)

Answer (score 2):

**Loading**. As in, "After the loading of the data, the system went down."

That's just the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

According to the OED, it's just **loading**. (Also, it's not a 'passive verb'; it's a noun that is often used in the passive voice.)

> **loading** *noun*
>
> a. The action of the verb load v.; the placing of a load or cargo in a vehicle, vessel, etc.

This definition is similar to that of "transformation":

> **transformation** *noun*
>
> a. The action of changing in form, shape, or appearance; metamorphosis.

**Sidenote:**

There is an entry for "loadage", but that's an obsolete word for a toll, it would seem.

> **loadage** *noun (obsolete)*
>
> A toll or due for loading.